# Simple XOR (PHP & C#)

Tags: c#, php, .net, winforms, xor

is it possible to have some sort of **very** simple reversible encryption in php that can be reversed using C# Winforms?

thank you

Comment: Ooh sorry. I'd just like to encrypt a string of text on my webpage. And then in my c# winforms app be able to reverse that encrypted text.

Comment: Technically speaking, XORing your data with a randomly generated string of bytes is essentially what encryption, strong or weak, does. It all depends on how the string was "randomly" generated that determines whether the result is strong or weak encryption. If it's some fixed static string, then it's weak.

Comment: @j-t-s: By "encryption" you mean "obfuscation"?  Encryption has much stronger guarantees.

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant to say obfuscation. Obfuscation isn't in my everyday vocab so I generally forget things I don't use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. In the PHP part you can use the bitwise operator `^`, but you'll first have to convert the string into an array of integers (e.g. `array_map('ord', str_split($str))`) and then do an inner product with the one-time pad, xor taking the role of multiplication and concatenation taking the role of addition.

Remember that if you re-use the pad, the security of the encryption falls apart.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Algorithms are not language specific.